# Where can I find xamarin ios device log?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I am working with xamarin forms I am getting this error

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error       error MT1006: Could not install the application '/Users/thiagofmartins/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/neoFly_Montana.iOS/b6e2debf676f3efdb9da75d6f5344ce4/bin/iPhone/Debug/neoFly_Montana.iOS.app' on the device 'iPhone de THIAGO': Your code signing/provisioning profiles are not correctly configured. Probably you have an entitlement not supported by your current provisioning profile, or your device is not part of the current provisioning profile. Please check the iOS Device Log for details (error: 0xe8008016).

its appears in my visual studio on windows, which I am using with a mac to launch my app in a Iphone device.

I think, maybe in the IOS Device log I can see more details about this error, but, where can I found that? Only in a Mac, or I can see in my windows visual studio?? Do I need transfer my project to a mac to see that?

Comment: did you try all these https://support.kaspersky.com/12419
https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/Native+iOS+Debugging+and+Testing+Tools

if you don't have Xcode the please intall Apple Configurator2 from app store & read device log as given in link https://community.sophos.com/kb/en-us/113906

Comment: Can't I see that in the device log on my Visual studio in my windows?

Comment: Please use a Mac system. Either user Xcode or Apple Configurator for device log.

Comment: ok.. sorry here is something from Xamarin about device log https://blog.xamarin.com/enhanced-device-logging-in-visual-studio/

Comment: no problem. Thank you very much

Comment: Updated blog link: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/enhanced-device-logging-in-visual-studio/

Answer (score 6):

Open terminal and type the following to the display the log of the devices connected over USB to your Mac:

/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/bin/mtouch --logdev